# Trigger a (change) event on form-control from code

Tags: angular, angular6, dom-events, form-control

While setting the value of a form-control in a form-group in Javascript

```js
this.daysFormGroup.controls["Id"].setValue("Val");
```

the [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) event is not triggered.

Any suggestions ?
Is there any other way to call a (change) event from *Angular6* code?

Comment: Can you show more code, where have you registered `(change)` event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for `change` event on `formControl`, then you can use [valueChanges](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges) event provided by `angular`. No need to register additional `change` event.

You can subscribe to the event inside `ngOnInit()`

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.daysFormGroup.controls["Id"]
              .valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
                    // called everytime when form control value is updated
                    this.myFunOnChange();  // call the method that you are trying to call on (change)
                 });
}
```